# Best SharePoint design for patients and checkups lists with document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

What would be the best design for a SharePoint online/2013 site where doctors/nurses could create patients, and add/link different scanned documents to these patients, while having some checkup information added multiple times.

So patientA is created, blood test documents are added to patientA, and a checkup on day1 are logged as a comment. The next checkup on day2 is added to this patient. Maybe some IRM scan document is added to the patient.

Maybe 2 "linked" lists (patient, checkup) with attachments?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done under one site by linking lists using lookup fields. So, you can have one list to store patients information, a document library with lookup column to the patients, and a list for checkups with lookup to the patient. On the landing page, you can create a little dash board as my colleague David Lozzi has explained in his blog post [here](https://davidlozzi.com/2012/08/02/creating-an-item-detail-dashboard-view-of-your-joined-lists-in-sharepoint-2010/)